# Unzipped Files Missing When Unzipped to Zip Parent Directory on Network

Tags: windows-7, networking, zip

**Related to but not the same as:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509013/files-not-displaying-in-windows-explorer-following-vba-unzip

In trying to solve the above linked question, I have stopped using VBA because I am growing more and more confident the issue lies outside of VBA and Excel.

**The Problem:** When I unzip a zip file to its parent directory on a network drive in Windows 7, the zip file's contents do not show up until I further manipulate files in that directory.

**Steps to Recreate:**

1. Navigate to a network folder.
2. Create a text file called "Text1"
3. Create a text file called "Text2"
4. Zip the text files together into a single zip by selecting both, then right-clicking and selecting Send to Compressed (Zipped) Folder
5. Delete the two original files.
6. Right-click on the zip file and do Extract All, and then put the network folder as the destination.
7. Neither Text1 nor Text2 should be visible.
8. Right-click somewhere in the folder and select "Refresh" and verify that neither text file is visible.
9. Right-click on the zip file and do Extract All, and then extract to the default directory, one inside the network folder with the same name of the zip file.
10. Refresh the parent directory and Text2 should be visible.
11. Repeat Step 6.
12. Refresh and Text1 should not be visible.
13. Repeat Step 9.
14. Refresh and Text1 should be visible.

**Desired Behavior:**
That all of my zip contents appear in the destination folder when I first unzip them, even if the destination is the same as the zip file and even if the file is in a network folder.

**The Question:**
Why does this happen and how can I obtain my desired behavior?

Comment: Does the behaviour differ if you use a third-party archiver such as 7-Zip?

Comment: I have not tried using a 3rd party archiver, though that is a good question. I'm on a corporate network automating a task that will be passed around, so I'd prefer not to have to do that if possible. I think my backup plan if no one can answer my question using native Windows functions will be to unzip to a non-network folder and copy over, and then the third option would be to ask permission (*grimace*) to put portable 7-zip on our network folder for our use.